# CUPS printing How to get job number when submitting job?

Tags: linux, scripting, printing, cups

I am working with [CUPS](http://cups.org/) and trying to wrap some job monitoring around it. Is there any way for me to get the job number when I use the lpr to submit the job?

Alternatively, is there any other tool that will show me the list of jobs that are printed and give me the file name submitted for that job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use "lp" instead of "lpr". "lp" will return a JOB ID after job submission. `lp -d printername` instead of `lpr -P printername`

```
[root@server ~]# lp -d office /etc/ntp.conf 
request id is office-5330836 (1 file(s))
```